# Can the Gennorm v1 become Cauchy distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Can the [Generalized normal distribution Version 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution#Version_1) become a [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) for any **sigma** size if I play around with the **beta** variable? (in the sense that gennorm(sigma_a,beta_b)=cauchy(sigma_c) where sigma_a could be equal to sigma_c but doesnt have to be), cases where the gennorm will distribution will become a cauchy distribution)

If yes then for what beta/sigma values?

Comment: no because the generalised normal distribution always has an exponential term for any $\beta$, but the cauchy doesn't